# Android imageview performance, 1 or 3 images in layout?

Tags: android, performance, memory, imageview, rendering

I would like to know what is more efficient in an aspect of rendering and memory consumption?

Let's assume that always will be visible one image.
What is more efficient having 3 images in a layout and changing visibility of them, or changing imageResource programatically of 1 image?

Here is an example:

Case #1

```
<!-- View case 1 -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/img_1" />
    
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/img_2" />
    
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/img_3" />
</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
// Implementation Case #1
fun showImg2() {
    binding.img1.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    binding.img2.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    binding.img3.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
}
```

---

Case #2

```
<!-- View case 2 -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/img_1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
// Implementation Case #2
fun showImg2() {
    binding.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_2)
}
```

What is more efficient in an aspect of rendering and memory consumption?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously case 2 is more efficient.
If you convert your images to **webp** it will be better than best.

Comment: Great did not know **webp** is supported in Android.
CDN web services like ImageKit can be also helpful.
I would leave the question still here maybe someone makes some measurings.
My opinion is that case 1 is better for processor but worse for memory, and case 2 better for memory but worse for processor.